# Finding Route in specific Bundle

Tags: routes, symfony

I am implementing a web app using symfony 2. It has a main page that is served through a "CoreBundle" which loads up the contents of other app bundles within a div. To handle this, I want to have the CoreBundle route catch all routes and then forward the request to the app bundles in order to get the content within the div.

the route is:

```
@Route("{app_name}/{garbage}", name="_core_app_garbage", requirement={"garbage"=".*"})
```

This works great. It captures all routes with $app_name set to the name of the app (the first subdirectory), and the rest of the uri inside $garbage.

My problem is trying to find the route for $garbage within the specific app. The core bundle has knowledge of the bundle name for the app.

So far I have tried the following two things:

1. Use the router service to find the route but trying to remove the catch all route:

   ```
   $router->getRouteCollection()->remove("_core_app_garbage");
   ```

   That doesn't seem to change anything (the route I get back is still the catch all).
2. Creating my own router. I tried various configurations but it seems to take a lot of class creations and specific class creations ( AnnotationDirectoryLoader in my case ). That seems overly difficult to what I am used to with Symfony and it is not portable if I decide to change the routing format (to YAML for example).

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried moving the catch all route to the bottom of your routing config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pretty good solution, although it isn't perfect:

Basically I load the route collection for a specific bundle using the 'routing.loader' service. Then I create my own UrlMatcher to match against those routes.

```
// Get the route collection for the app's bundle
$kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
$routingFilesLocation = $kernel->locateResource( '@'. $app->getBundle() . '/Controller/' );
$routeLoader = $this->container->get('routing.loader');
$collection = $routeLoader->load( $routingFilesLocation );

// Ensure that we don't get in a redirect loop when
// loading the dashboard of core
$collection->remove( '_core_redirect_home' );

// Try to match the rest of the url to one of the routes
$router = $this->container->get('router');
$routeString = $routingFilesLocation . "<br/>";
$url =  "/" . $garbage;

$matcher = new UrlMatcher( $collection, $router->getContext() );
try
{
    $routes = $matcher->match( $url );
}
catch( ResourceNotFoundException $e )
{
    throw $this->createNotFoundException( 'Could not find "' . $url . '" route within ' . $app_name );
}
$response = $this->forward( $routes['_controller'] );
```

The problem here is that I have hard coded to only look for controllers in the "Controller" folder within the bundle.